# Scroll bar on code area should be always visible

Tags: discussion

There are times when the code visible in the view area appears complete but there is actually more to view once you scroll as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931344/my-application-keeps-crashing-every-time).

I understand this is not a very major issue as people ought to read the questions very carefully before answering. But if a new user were to come across such a question, he/she probably wouldn't know to scroll and check if there is more code to see.

Would it make sense to make the scroll bar always visible or any other marker to suggest the same?

Comment: I see 2 scroll bars in that code block.

Comment: @Cerbrus only when you attempt to scroll. What if you never tried to scroll because you did not know there was more to see?

Comment: No, even when I simply load the page I see 2 scroll bars (x / y). I'm on the latest Google Chrome, by the way.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't see the scroll bars when I load the page on the latest Safari and latest Firefox

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Every single browser I have installed shows 2 scoll bars on page load. (That's IE, FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari on Win 8.1)

Comment: @Cerbrus I just tried in the Chrome for Mac, don't see scrollbars there either. I am running OS X Yosemite

Comment: What's your screen resolution?

Comment: @Cerbrus so it is a Mac OS X issue. If it can be of help, my display is 2560 x 1600 (retina)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Mac OS X, this is the default for all scrollable areas and is something Stack Overflow has limited control over. If you don't like this behaviour, go to System Preferences → General → Show scroll bars: Always. Otherwise, better get used to the behaviour. The scroll bars should flash briefly when the scrollable area is displayed as a visual cue.

For Stack Overflow to work around that they'd have to implement [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317634/force-visible-scrollbar-in-firefox-on-mac-os-x) which will affect more systems than just OS X; which is unreasonable to "fix" behaviour of a single operating system which is arguably not even "wrong".

For question posters: if you need to post more code than fits in the default visible code block area, you're probably posting too much code and need to trim it down to get to a reasonable question.